# Is it possible to have rate predictions which are greater than 1 with Poisson regression in r?

Tags: r, stan

I was trying to fit the Poisson rate regression and predict the rate by using `StanMoMo` in R. However, when I tried to extract `mufor`(The predictions were saved in this variable) from the result. Few values were greater than zero. It was very strange. Since I tried to use the sample dataset that the author provided, there was no such problem. So I am wondering why is this the case. Please give me some suggestions, Thank you!

I may not be available to provide the original dataset. I am still trying my best to generate a reproducible example.